# How to Find a current day in c language?

Tags: c

I am able to get the current date but the output is like 9/1/2010,but my requirement is to get the current day like"Wednesday" not in form of integer value like 1.
My code is here.

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
struct date d;
getdate(&d);
printf("The current year is: %d\n", d.da_year);
printf("The current day is: %d\n", d.da_day);
printf("The current month is: %d\n", d.da_mon);
getch();
return 0;

}
```

Please help me to find the current day as Sunday,Monday.........
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you really writing for 16-bit DOS, or just using some weird outdated tutorial?

[`strftime`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strftime/) is available in any modern C library:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[32];
    struct tm *ts;
    size_t last;
    time_t timestamp = time(NULL);

    ts   = localtime(&timestamp);
    last = strftime(buffer, 32, "%A", ts);
    buffer[last] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DYSyT

Comment: this doesn't give you the day, it just formats the date so that the information you need is somewhere in the middle

Answer (score 4):

The headers you are using are nonstandard. Use functions from the standard:

```
#include <time.h>

struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
```

After you call the function above, you can get the weekday from:

```
tm->tm_wday
```

Check out this [tutorial/example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/rzan5mst156.htm).

There's [more documentation with examples here](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/time.h/ctime.php).

As others have pointed out, you can use `strftime` to get the weekday name once you have a `tm`. There's a good example [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strftime.3.html#EXAMPLES):

```
   #include <time.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       char outstr[200];
       time_t t;
       struct tm *tmp;

       t = time(NULL);
       tmp = localtime(&t);
       if (tmp == NULL) {
           perror("localtime");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (strftime(outstr, sizeof(outstr), "%A", tmp) == 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("Result string is \"%s\"\n", outstr);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you insist on using your outdated compiler, there's a `dosdate_t` struct in `<dos.h>`:

```
struct dosdate_t {
  unsigned char  day;       /* 1-31          */
  unsigned char  month;     /* 1-12          */
  unsigned short year;      /* 1980-2099     */
  unsigned char  dayofweek; /* 0-6, 0=Sunday */
};
```

You fill it with:

```
void _dos_getdate(struct dosdate_t *date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `struct tm` [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Development/Converttmstructuretotimetvaluehowtousemktime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` is certainly the right way to go. Of course you could do

```
char * weekday[] = { "Sunday", "Monday",
                       "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                       "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
char *day = weekday[d.da_day];
```

I'm of course assuming that the value `getdate()` puts in the `date` struct is 0-indexed, with Sunday as the first day of the week. (I don't have a DOS box to test on.)